# How to load the json result set into the java script variable

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am looking to load the Json result into javascript variable. So how can i load the json result url or Controller action into the javascript variable.

I used javascript to auto suggest the values in input field.

The below code is works when i use the static data with the variable. But when i pass the url or Controller action its not working.

**Script**

```
 <script>
$(function () {
    var CorporateNameSearch = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",          
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",          
      "Scheme"
    ];

    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: CorporateNameSearch
    });
});
```

**View page**

```
  <div class="form-group">
         <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="tags">Some value:</label>                            
         <div class="col-sm-9">                
         <input type="text" id="tags" name="tags" class="form-control" />
         </div>
  </div>
```

**Controller** Which returns JSON result

```
  public ActionResult JsonData()
    {
        int ProviderID = 100;
        string ProfileUrl = "http://localhost:64423/api/CorporateName/CorporateDetails?pid=" + ProviderID + "";
        System.Net.Http.HttpClient DashBoardclient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
        DashBoardclient.BaseAddress = new Uri(ProfileUrl);
        DashBoardclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        DashBoardclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        HttpResponseMessage dashboardresponseMessage = DashBoardclient.GetAsync(ProfileUrl).Result;
        var DashboardData = dashboardresponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        return Json(DashboardData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);            
    }
```

**Script I tried to load json result**

```
  var myjson;
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:49359/ConfirmVisit/JsonData", function (json) {
    myjson = json;
   });

     $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: myjson 
    });
```

So, how can i pass the url of json result or controller action into the java script variable to work auto suggest in my view page?

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: What is the value of `DashboardData`? - it needs to be `IEnumerable<string>` (and do not hard code you url like that - use `var url = '@Url.Action("JsonData", "ConfirmVisit")';`)

Comment: Value of DashboardData is like [{"GroupID":"7313","GroupName":"HUA YANG BERHAD"}] @StephenMuecke

Comment: That does not match what you need for you autocomplete - you need to send an object which is `IEnumerable<string>`

Comment: Can you give a sample code @StephenMuecke

Comment: I don't know what you want to send, but if you just use `var data = new List<string>(){ "ActionScript", "AppleScript", .... }; return Json(data , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` it will work fine.

Comment: But ajax is async and the value of `myjson` when applied to the autocomplete will be `null` because the ajax call will not have been completed by then. The source method needs to be set to a function which calls ajax (refer the [docs](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp) for an example)

Comment: Actually with your above mentioned code, the input field suggest. But it suggest the whole json result as one option. I cant able to select only one name..

Comment: Foe Example my result is ["[{\"GroupID\":\"7313\",\"GroupName\":\"HUA YANG BERHAD\"},{\"GroupID\":\"7314\",\"GroupName\":\"AGRO-MOD INDUSTRIES SDN BHD\"},{\"GroupID\":\"7316\",\"GroupName\":\"PROP PARK SDN BHD\"},{\"GroupID\":\"4606\",\"GroupName\":\"WAWASAN TEST I 3 \"},{\"GroupID\":\"4620\",\"GroupName\":\"MS ELEVATORS ENGINEERING SDN. BHD\"},{\"GroupID\":\"6820\",\"GroupName\":\"APPLIED BUSINESS SYSTEMS SDN BHD\"},{\"GroupID\":\"5487\",\"GroupName\":\"AEROTREE DEFENCE \u0026 SERVICES SDN. BHD.\"}]. When i starts to type somethnig in input it suggest the whole result as one option

Comment: Because all you passing back is a single string. You need to generate a `IEnumerable<string>` containing the values your want. Best guess is you want the values of `GroupName` in which case, deserialize it to an object and select just the `GroupName` values.

Comment: And put relevant details and code in your question, not comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136300/discussion-between-muzz-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `getJSON` call is asynchronous!

With your current code, It will try to make an ajax call to the JsonData action method, but you are registering the autocomplete functionality with `myjson` variable. What if the server takes 10 seconds to return the response ? You are updating the `myjson` in the success callback(when the server response came), but you already invoked(registered) the `autocomplete` with the original value of the `myjson` variable!

When dealing with ajax calls, make sure you are using the response/data from the ajax call after you received it from server. Most ajax methods has success callback methods which will be executed after a response is received from the server call.

Register your autocomplete when you get the result from the ajax call, inside the success callback.

```
$(function () {

    $.getJSON("@Url.Action("JsonData")", function (json) {
        $("#tags").autocomplete({
            source: json
        });
    });

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `myjson = JSON.parse(myjson)`.

This will convert the JSON text into a javascript object, which can be used in your js code.

Comment: Nope...its not working @Jersh... still there is no auto suggestion in input field